# Replacing a specific menu item

Tags: php, menus

So, I understand how to target a specific menu using the following to add a custom code.

```
<?php

wp_nav_menu(
 array(
  'menu' => 'Project Nav',
  // do not fall back to first non-empty menu
  'theme_location' => '__no_such_location',
  // do not fall back to wp_page_menu()
  'fallback_cb' => false
 )
 );

?>
```

Question I have is the following.

Let say I have a menu called "primary". Within this menu, there are 4 menu items (picture below).

[image]

One of the items is called "Profile".

I want to replace the word "Profile" with the following code which shows user profile photo instead of the word "Profile".

```
    <?php global $my_profile; ?>
    <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
    <div class="img" data-key="profile"><?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

So, the final result would look like this:

[image]

Now, how can I specifically target a menu item title?

EDIT:

So, I got the following based and I am not sure why it is not working.

```
function nav_replace_wpse_189788($item_output, $item, $args) {
 //var_dump($item_output, $item);
 if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
  return $items;

   if ('royal_profile_menu_title' == $item->title) {
    global $my_profile;

    if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
      return '<div class="img" data-key="profile">'.get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ).'</div>';
        }
    }
  }
   return $item_output;
 }
 add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','nav_replace_wpse_189788',10,2);
```

Here is my logic. First target the "primary" menu, then look for item title "royal_profile_menu_title" then replace the word title with the output

(My menu title is "royal_profile_menu_title": Picture below)
[image]

Any

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is relatively easily done using the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter (without all that PHP tag spam):

```
function nav_replace_wpse_189788($item_output, $item) {
  //   var_dump($item_output, $item);
  if ('Profile' == $item->title) {
    global $my_profile; // no idea what this does?
    if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
      return '<div class="img" data-key="profile">'.get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ).'</div>';
    }
  }
  return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','nav_replace_wpse_189788',10,2);
```

Note: I had to edit your code to `return` a string, not `echo` one. You may need to tweak the `if` conditional. Uncomment the `var_dump()` to see what you have to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So, I edited the code you provided and updated the question. I am not getting any result yet. Could you be able to look it over and why it is not working?

Comment: Uncomment that `var_dump` and look at the data. The code does work if you get the conditional right. I can't really guess at the specifics of your install.

Comment: I used this answer on a similar question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398751/replace-menu-a-tag-with-button-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Presonally, I would use some CSS workaround. In menu administration you can add CSS class to menu item (if the field is not displayed, you can find it in Screen Options), for example "profile-link".

And than you can add something like this to your template HEAD section:

```
<?php
$avatar = get_avatar_url( get_current_user_id(), array('size' => 64) ); // from WP 4.2
$image_url = $avatar['url'];
?>

<style type="text/css">
.menu li.profile-link { background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url ?>); /* + another CSS*/  }
.menu li.profile-link span { display: none; }
</style>
```

And add to your `wp_nav_menu` function `'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>'` options.

Not tested, but it should do the job.