# Replace menu <a> tag with <button> tag

Tags: menus, navigation

I have the following menu setup via header.php:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="header__nav-items">%3$s</ul>',
    )
);
```

This spits out the following on the front-end:

```
<ul class="header__nav-items">
    <li class="header__nav-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" class="header__nav-anchor">Parent</a><!-- I'd like to replace this <a> tag with a <button> tag. -->
        <ul class="header__sub-menu">
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-one" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page One</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-two" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Two</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-three" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Three</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-four" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've implemented a custom field ([with ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)) so that admin can select whether or not the menu item is a dropdown via WP-Admin.

[image: ACF WP menu radio button]

I then have the following via functions.php:

```
<?php
function edit_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        if ( get_field( 'dropdown', $item) == 'yes' ) {
            echo '<button class="nav__button>'.$item->title.'</button>';
        }
    }
    return $items;  
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'edit_menu_item', 10, 2);
```

I was expecting the above to output the following on the front-end:

```
<ul class="header__nav-items">
    <li class="header__nav-item menu-item-has-children">
        <button class="header__button">Parent</button>
        <ul class="header__sub-menu">
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-one" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page One</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-two" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Two</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-three" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Three</a></li>
            <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="child-page-four" class="header__nav-anchor">Child Page Four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Instead, the button has been placed outside of the menu, like so:

```
<button class="header__button">Parent</button><!-- Button appearing here -->
<ul class="header__nav-items">
<!-- Rest of the markup -->
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you may be looking for wp_nav_menu_items hook (instead of wp_nav_menu_objects): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

Comment: I think this hook is used for filtering the whole menu list, not individual items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the above can be achieved with the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter ([see reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/)).

```
<?php
function edit_menu_item($item_output, $item) {
    if ( get_field( 'dropdown', $item) == 'yes' ) { 
        return '<button>'.$item->title.'</button>';
    }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el','edit_menu_item', 10, 2);
```

Credit goes to [@s_ha_dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) [via this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189788/replacing-a-specific-menu-item).